# Rack Pick in a custom flowchart with a dynamic event

Tags: anylogic

I would like to use my custom flowchart for different process flows and my target is to pick my pallets from the racks to the certain times from my dbase. So with a delay block it doesn't work so I replaced it by a wait block where I will release the pallets which should get picked by the time of my dbase. The function doesn't work and I'm not sure if it is the right way to solve my problem. **I would like to release the number of pallets (n) to the picktime of my dbase.**
Thank you for your help!

[image: dbase]

[image: customflowchart]

[image: dynamicevent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DE looks good but you are calling it from a wrong location, that is what the error is telling you. Make sure you access that location first before calling `create_DE...`.

(depends on where you call it from and where it lives, see https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fcode%2FAccess.html&resultof=%22%77%68%65%72%65%22%20%22%61%6d%22%20%22%69%22%20